# smartcrop-cli - How can i execute it with php exec?

Tags: php, node.js, exec, node-modules

```
https://github.com/jwagner/smartcrop-cli
```

After installing smartcrop, i can execute

```
/usr/bin/smartcrop --width 100 --height 100 photo.jpg square-thumbnail.jpg
```

in my terminal and it works good. It is a node module and i am not sure whether it can be accessed with php's exec.

when i try

```
exec('/usr/bin/smartcrop --width 100 --height 100 photo.jpg square-thumbnail.jpg')
```

it is not working. How to use smartcrop cli with php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try running your script in `php` from the commandline (instead of from the browser):
something like: `$ php -f script.php`.
Sometimes the problem is with permissions.
In the script, I would use:
`exec('nohup /usr/bin/smartcrop --width 100 --height 100 photo.jpg square-thumbnail.jpg &');`

Comment: It works good with command line php. Which permission is blocking it from running?

Comment: when you execute a script from the commandline, you are using the current user's permissions. When running from the browser, you use permissions for www-data user. See this http://superuser.com/a/646070/627509 for how to give www-data write permissions in a folder, which should solve your problem and allow you to run within a browser as well.